# Adding a gem dynamically from within a rake task

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, bundler

I am trying to use the `mongo` gem for a data migration rake task. I don't want to add it to the `Gemfile` for the whole project just so it can be used from this single rake task. How do I dynamically add `mongo` to the bundle for just that rake task?

I have tried using `Bundler::Injector::inject`, but then I need to `bundle install`. If I run that from within the task, the bundler has already initialized, so the `require 'mongo'` still fails. Should I do something to reload the bundler or is there actually a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add it to your Gemfile with `:require => false`:

```
gem "mongo", :require => false
```

This will allow bundler to install it and set up the load path, but it won't actually load the gem.

In your rake task, just `require "mongo"` to load it when you need it.

Comment: I was asking how to allow a rake task to `require 'mongo'` without forcing everyone to install it, since it is only needed for a one-off task.